# Programmatically setting Flash security in Linux

Tags: linux, flash, docker

We have a server which has to fire some automated jobs using Flash. There is some code which fires off a webpage hosting the Flash content. This is hosted in a Docker environment and is all automated.

Because of the nature of the Flash files, it is required that the folder containing the Flash file is added to the Global Security Settings panel.

I understand that the settings are designed in a way to maintain security for users. However as I have access to all the files on the machine is there any way for me to set these either programmatically or through the command line.

I have been able to work out that the settings are saved in a Shared Object file called settings.sol in the config folder -

```
/home/chrome/.config/google-chrome/Default/Pepper Data/Shockwave Flash/WritableRoot/#SharedObjects/BDAYM3AG/macromedia.com/support/flashplayer/sys
```

I have tried copying a pre-set settings file from a previous configuration to this directory on spinning up the server / Docker container.

However as soon as the Flash content is run this is overwritten (presumably it knows that the settings were created for a different user / machine).

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Thanks

Zak

Answer (score 0):

Try to create `.../WritableRoot/#Security/FlashPlayerTrust/<any_name>.cfg` and add paths to folders with your swf files into that *.cfg file.